# Flex viewstack addchild dynamically without recreating each child

Tags: apache-flex, repeater, addchild, viewstack

I have a viewstack with a repeater inside to create each child. Soemthing like that:

```
    <mx:ViewStack width="100%" height="100%" >
    <mx:Repeater id="myrepeater" dataProvider="{myDataProvider}">
    <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" >
    ---view content goes here---
    </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Repeater>  
    </mx:ViewStack>
```

When I add an item to the dataprovider, it creates the new child, but it also reloads all the other children, which I don't want. How do I prevent Flex from recreating the component when it adds a child?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how helpful this is; but don't use a repeater; XML wasn't designed for loops.  Re-write your code in ActionScript..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it "incrementally" with a Repeater, you should do it programmatically instead using the method *addChild()* which belongs to Container hence it's inherited by, for example, the HBox at the first level inside your Repeater,

cheers

Comment: Thanks. I finally got to doing it like you suggested. It solves the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Flex 4 or higher, then use a `DataGroup` or a `List` instead of a `Repeater`. Everything will just work better.

Otherwise, you can try setting `recycleChildren=false` on the Repeater.